# Can you have curving, empty, broken arrows in xymatrix?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

In \xymatrix, the command
`\ar@{}[dr] |{\text{lab}}`
typesets an empty arrow, broken by some text.  Similarly, the command
`\ar@/^10pt/ @{->}[ur] |{\text{lab}}`
typesets a curving arrow, broken by some text.  I would expect
`\ar@/^10pt/ @{}[ur] |{\text{lab}}`
then to typset a curving, empty arrow, broken by some text, but it doesn't.  Is there a convenient way to achieve curving, empty, broken?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}  
\usepackage[all]{xy}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{equation}  
\xymatrix{  
a \ar@/^10pt/ @{}[r] |{\text{lab}} & b  
}  
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but replacing `\ar@{}` by `\ar@{{ }{ }}` or `\ar@{ { }}` works. But `\ar@{{ } }` does not :). A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{a \ar @{{ }{ }} @/^10pt/ [r] |{\text{lab}} & b}
\end{document}
```

If someone knows why this happens, edit me. My guess is that being more explicit to `xy` helps it.